# Coffeescript existential operator sometimes checks against undefined, but not always

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This coffeescript...

```
if x? isnt '' then console.log x
```

Compiles to this javascript...

```
if ((typeof x !== "undefined" && x !== null) !== '') {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Where `typeof x` is checked against `undefined`

However, if I use `x` in the current scope, coffeescript explicitly declares it at the to of the scope, and then does not bother checking for `undefined`...

This coffeescript...

```
x = y.z
if x? isnt '' then console.log x
```

Compiles to this javascript...

```
var x;

x = y.z;

if ((x != null) !== '') {
  console.log(x);
}
```

It is possible that `x` ends up being `undefined` if `y.z` is `undefined`. Why does coffeescript not feel the need to check for undefined in the if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the more obvious case, the second example:

The compiler knows that `var x` is declared, even if it is not defined, so all it needs to do is check that the value isn't `null` or `undefined` which can be done with `x != null`.

However, this isn't the case in the first example. `x` hasn't been declared anywhere, so trying `x != null` would actually throw a `ReferenceError`, however `typeof x` will return a value (and if `x` is in fact not `null` or `undefined` all will be will in the universe.